# Error using read.table due to colCLasses

Tags: r, read.table

I'm trying to import a CSV using read.table. Since specifying colClasses makes it faster, I tried to use it (it works without colCLasses, so I definitely know this is the issue). The following is the error I got:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
scan() expected 'an integer', got 'N44EU'
```

Now, this might be due to some mismatch in the classes specified, but I used this method to find the classes:

```
classes <- sapply(table_name,class)
```

Further, in the read.table function, for the argument colClasses, I inputted classes. This is when I got the error.

**Full code:**

```
initial <- read.table("Dognition.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",", quote="",na.strings = "NA")
classes <- sapply(initial,class)
final <- read.table("Dognition.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",", quote="",na.strings = "NA", colClasses= classes)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Can you show `print(classes)` and `head(initial)` output?

Comment: If speed is needed, then it's worth checking `data.table::fread`

Answer (score 0):

Sheesh. The error was that there were some formulae in my worksheet. When I converted the excel into CSV, I forgot to paste these as values. Once I did this and repeated the process, I didn't get the error!Lesson learnt.